# Trying to create an array to find occurrence of character in a given String. Only allowed to use methods length and charAt from the class String

Tags: java, arrays

Trying to create an array to find the occurrence of a character in a given String.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  String s1 = "java";
  char ch = 'a';
 
System.out.println(indexOf(s1, ch));
}

public static int indexOf(String s, char ch)
{
  int count = 0;
  
  while (count < s.length())
  {
     if (s.charAt(count) == ch)
        return count;
        
     else
        count += 1;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

So the result is supposed to be 1 3

Comment: Where is the array supposed to be ? Because your code is ok for now

Comment: @azro int[] arr = indexOf(s1, ch);
Something like this in the main method?

Comment: And what do you put in that array ? all the indexes where you found the value ?

Comment: Yes, so whenever ch occurs in string s1, the index where it occurs will be copied and printed out

Comment: Please edit your post and share en aexample of input/output you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the restrictions you have, you will have to first create an array with the size equal to the length of the string (assuming a condition when all chars are same). Then, iterate the characters of the given string and store the index where a match with the given character is found. Finally, copy the initialised positions of this array to another array and return the same. In case, no match is found, simply return `new int[] { -1 }`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        String s1 = "java";
        char ch = 'a';

        int[] array = indexOf(s1, ch);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

        array = indexOf(s1, 'x');
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }

    public static int[] indexOf(String s, char ch) {
        // The maximum size can be the length of the string i.e. when all chars are same
        int[] array = new int[s.length()];
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == ch) {
                array[count++] = i;
            }
        }
        if (count == 0) {
            return new int[] { -1 };
        } else {
            // Create an array result[], of the size = count and copy elements from array[]
            // to it
            int[] result = new int[count];
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                result[i] = array[i];
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 3]
[-1]
```

Comment: Sorry but forgot to mention the method is int[] and not just int.
The output is supposed to be 1 and 3 since 'a' occurs twice in "java"

Comment: @DanielAdams - I've updated the answer based on this clarification. I have added a new function, `count` for this new requirement. Feel free to comment in case of any further issue/doubt.

Comment: @DanielAdams -  I've updated the answer based on this further clarification. Feel free to comment in case of any further issue/doubt.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the indexes where a char occurs in a string, you need a value that marks the position in the string, and the other the nulber of matches, to know the position in the result array, and at the end, cut the array to remove the leading unused boxes

```
public static int[] indexOf(String s, char ch) {
    int count = 0;
    int[] result = new int[s.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == ch) {
            result[count] = i;
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    return Arrays.copyOf(result, count); // cut to keep indexes only
}
```

Demo

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(indexOf("java", 'a')));        // [1, 3]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(indexOf("abahauayata", 'a'))); // [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(indexOf("aaaaaaabbbb", 'a'))); // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: @DanielAdams the toString is just to show the result^^ I'm bored of unallowed methods sorry I won't modify more. From my code, you can modify a few to reach your requirement

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[] indexOf(String s, char ch) {
    int total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        if (s.charAt(i) == ch)
            total++;

    if (total == 0)
        return new int[0];

    int[] res = new int[total];

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        if (s.charAt(i) == ch)
            res[j++] = i;

    return res;
}
```